# GPG can't check signature

Tags: compiling, deb, gnupg

I was trying to recompile and rebuild libevent2 source from oneiric on my natty server and I had a small error with gpg not being able to check signature

```
# dpkg-source -x libevent_2.0.12-stable-1.dsc
gpgv: Signature made Fri Jun 17 07:12:50 2011 PDT using DSA key ID 7ADF9466
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./libevent_2.0.12-stable-1.dsc
```

Any idea how to fix this warning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you should import the key to local keyring as @enzotib instructed:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7ADF9466
```

Then export the key to your local trustedkeys to make it trusted:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring -a --export 7ADF9466 | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ~/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg --import -
```

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 16.04 where `~/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg` did not exist.

Answer (score 12):

I believe the conventional solution is to install the [GnuPG keys of Debian Developers](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/debian-keyring/) package:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring
```

Comment: Yes, the gpg commands suggested here by @enzotib and @Flint did not work for me on Ubuntu 14.04, at least for enabling validation when running `apt-get source`. But installing the `debian-keyring` package worked, as @ændrük suggests.

Answer (score 6):

You should import the key to local keyring with the following command:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7ADF9466
```

Then, try again the command.

Comment: Thanks but it still failed to verify the signature

Comment: @Flint: you are running as root, so also this command should be run as root, to go to root keyring. Have you done so?

Comment: Are there any official sources documenting that this approach is secure? How could I know that `7ADF9466` is indeed the correct signing key if it does not exist in the keyring package? What prevents a man in the middle from serving a `dsc` file signed with a different key (possibly even a different key with the same 32 bit hash).