# Ubuntu 10.10 release-upgrade fails

Tags: upgrade

Just tried to upgrade my ubuntu 10.10 using "do-release-upgrade" from console and fails:
Error is:

```
alex@spse:/# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1306kB]
Fetched 1307kB in 0s (0B/s)
authenticate 'natty.tar.gz' against 'natty.tar.gz.gpg'
exception from gpg: GnuPG exited non-zero, with code 2
Debug information:
gpg: Signature made Mon Jun  4 09:40:31 2012 EDT using DSA key ID 437D05B5
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
alex@spse:/#
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Are you [using the old-releases server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)? Also, what's your ultimate goal? If you can specify that, it might be possible for alternative methods to be suggested.

Comment: See this question: [GPG can't check signature](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56841/gpg-cant-check-signature)... Run the commands using the key appropriate for you, ie: replace `7ADF9466` with `437D05B5` when you run the commands.

Comment: Just tried using old-releases server. no luck. my goal is to upgrade to 12.04 lts; i wish to avoid a clean install.
Also just tried  your method Aditya - still no luck;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Eliah Kagan link then command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 437D05B5 3E5C1192
```

do-release-upgrade seems to work;

Even so, I don't know how safe it is to upgrade over ssh.
My current config is: ubuntu 10.10 installed on physical disk, and booted with vmware-player from windows 7.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You tried to update to natty (11.04) but 11.04 is EOL since October 28, 2012.
Take a look at this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

This is why you can't upgrade - the package you request doesent exist any more.

I think you have to reinstall with an actual Ubuntu-Version (12.04 or 12.10).
Or 13.04 which will be released at the End of April.

Comment: The 11.04 download do still exist, they've just been moved to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. `natty.tar.gz` exists and was downloaded, so the OP is *most likely* using that server, though I'm hoping the OP will clarify explicitly. Since some files exist, I don't think there's a *trivial* explanation for why other files, or other information, is unavailable. (I'm also not sure this usually happens when people try to perform an EoL upgrade like that.)

Comment: You say I can't upgrade?