# Can I do a release update on Ubuntu 7.10?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 7.10

I have an older server that still has Ubuntu 7.10, is there a way that I could update this since it is no longer supported?

`lsb_release -a` gives:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 7.10
Release:        7.10
Codename:       gutsy
```

I did the following instructions from here and they don't work for me:
[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) :

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then updated with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

and i get this error:

```
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Failed Upgrade tool signature
Failed Upgrade tool
Done downloading
extracting '/tmp/tmp8S5pl1/hardy.tar.gz'
Failed to extract
Extracting the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

Comment: @muru Is not the same question the guy ask how to install a new software on an older release, I need to upgrade the realese entirely not just some specific pieces of software

Comment: @muru ok, i will look, but because the answer applies it doesn't make it a dup question

Comment: @muru doesn't work, do I need a `sudo aptitude install update-manager-core update-manager` before doing a  `do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: @muru yes I did, I did the sed and checked the repo is changed, I get `Checking for a new ubuntu release
Failed Upgrade tool signature
Failed Upgrade tool
Done downloading
extracting '/tmp/tmptabge1/hardy.tar.gz'
Failed to extract
Extracting the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
`

Comment: Ok, nominated for reopening.  This might be related: http://askubuntu.com/q/279861/158442

Comment: @Mitch question was edited

Comment: @EliahKagan quwstion was edited

Comment: @muru So this turned out not to be a duplicate, because the methods described in the duplicate do not apply here? Independent of this question, does it make sense to add the new answer from here to the duplicate, so next time, a similar question does match the expected duplicate again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Eduard, based on my experience, I don't think upgrading directly from Ubuntu 7.10 will work, because there are just too many releases in between them.  Your old apt-get is probably not able to install the latest packages and perform all checks required.

I could think of doing incremental upgrades to 8.04(LTS), 10.04(LTS), 12.04(LTS) and 14.04(LTS), but that's a lot of work.

So the easiest path for you is probably reinstall Ubuntu 14.04(LTS) from scratch.  Before you start, make sure you have a reliable backup of your important server data, probably everything under /home and including server configuration under /etc.  I usually make a tarball from those trees, for reference.

Good luck!