# What's the official method for checking integrity of a source package?

Tags: apt, source-packages

I want to add a feature to pam, and I figured a good starting point was to download the `libpam-modules` source. On download, I notice this warning: `gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found`

What is the official method for verifying the integrity of source packages, when `apt-get` cannot find the public key?

The newest version of `ubuntu-keyring` and `debian-keyring` packages are installed already.

There are [ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56841/gpg-cant-check-signatur) to find the corresponding public key and install it. However that in itself does not provide integrity, because in effect it is trusting the contents of the `dsc` file to tell me which public key to use to verify the signature on the `dsc` file.

Is the gpg signature on the `dsc` file a critical part of the integrity verification? Could a man in the middle or a rouge mirror serve a malicious version of the file where the warning from gpg is the only indication something bad is happening? Or does `apt-get` have other means of validating the integrity?

Where would I find official documentation on the security model? Ideally I would like to understand the full trust path from the install image to the source package I am downloading.

The full output from the download was this:

```
$ apt-get source libpam-modules
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'pam' as source package instead of 'libpam-modules'
NOTICE: 'pam' packaging is maintained in the 'Bzr' version control system at:
https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/pam/ubuntu
Please use:
bzr branch https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/pam/ubuntu
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Need to get 2,043 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main pam 1.1.8-1ubuntu2 (dsc) [2,510 B]
Get:2 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main pam 1.1.8-1ubuntu2 (tar) [1,893 kB]
Get:3 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main pam 1.1.8-1ubuntu2 (diff) [147 kB]
Fetched 2,043 kB in 6s (316 kB/s)                                              
gpgv: Signature made Fri 31 Jan 2014 11:12:23 PM CET using RSA key ID 64792D67
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./pam_1.1.8-1ubuntu2.dsc
```

Comment: @Tim None of the answers to that other question site any official sources. They focus on making the warning go away, but it is unclear if they do so by verifying the integrity of the package or by simply suppressing the warning without performing a real integrity verification.

Comment: @kasperd It's not clear to you, maybe, in which case you could ask another question about how GPG works. But all the answers posted on http://askubuntu.com/questions/56841/gpg-cant-check-signature to date explain how to retrieve and install the correct public key and thus make the verification operate correctly. None of them explain how to silence the warning.

Comment: @Gilles None of them explains how to check which public key to use. The ID of the key to use appears to be taken straight out of the `dsc` file downloaded over http. What prevents a man in the middle from serving a `dsc` file signed with a different key?

Comment: @kasperd Then that key won't be the key of someone you trust.

Comment: @Gilles Right, it would not be the key of someone I trust. But the accepted answer you are referring me to suggests I just download and install it as a trusted key anyway. This is not a question about how gpg works, because using the signed message itself to find out which public key to use to verify the signature would be incorrect in any cryptosystem.

Comment: @kasperd On the contrary, the signed message always contains the public key, or enough information to retrieve it (how else would it work?). What cannot be contained in the message is the root of trust — what makes you, in the end, decide that the public key is one that you trust.

Comment: @Gilles You seem to be repeating yourself without paying attention to what I am saying. The answer you referred me to is suggesting I simply download the key which was used to sign the message and then install it as a trusted key thereby completely bypassing the entire web of trust.

Comment: @kasperd Read what I and others wrote more carefully instead of antagonizing people. The answer isn't suggesting to download this key because it's used to sign the message, but because that's the key used to sign Ubuntu packages. It happens to be the key used to sign the message because the message is authentic.

Comment: @Gilles Where are you getting that information from? I don't see it in the link you provided. The answers in the link you provided are doing the following: 1. Take the public key ID from the `dsc` file. 2. Download the corresponding public key. 3. Install it as a trusted key. You suggest it is an official key used to sign Ubuntu packages. It may be so, but where are you getting that information from?

Comment: @Gilles Even if the suggested method does work, it still doesn't answer my question. My question is, what the official way of checking the integrity of the package is. Are those GPG signatures really the official way of verifying the integrity? If so, why is so little attention payed to ensuring the keys are available by default, and why is the lack of key only treated as a warning by default? It happily extracts the tar file and applies the patch file, even without a key.

Comment: @Gilles Somebody care to explain why this got closed as duplicate? If you look at the accepted answers to each of the two questions, you'll see that they are completely different. If it was truly a duplicate question, the answers and questions would be interchangeable. But they are not. If you were to swap the accepted answers between the two questions, both answers would indeed be incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrity of the source package can be verified without validating the gpg signature on the `dsc` file.

Each installation source has a pair of files called `Release` and `Release.gpg`. These two files are the root of a hash tree, which can be used to validate the integrity of everything in the archive. The gpg signature on `Release` is the only one which need to be verified.

The signature on the `dsc` file may serve an important purpose before the file is put into a repository and indirectly signed through `Release.gpg`. Once the file is in the repository, the signature on the `dsc` file can be ignored.

Here is how I could manually verify the integrity. As far as I can tell, `apt-get source` does the same validation.

1. Download `http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release` and `http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg`.
2. Check the signature using `gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --verify Release.gpg Release` (The public key can also be found in `/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg`)
3. Download `http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources.gz`
4. Compare hashes obtained from `sha256sum Sources.gz` and `grep main/source/Sources.gz Release`
5. Compare hashes obtained from `sha256sum pam_1.1.8-1ubuntu2.dsc` and `zcat Sources.gz | grep pam_1.1.8-1ubuntu2.dsc`
6. Validate hashes found within the `dsc` file: `cat pam_1.1.8-1ubuntu2.dsc | sed -e 's/^ //;s/ [1-9][0-9]* /  /' | sha256sum -c`

Comment: I'll wait a couple of days before accepting my own answer to the question, just in case somebody can come up with a better answer.

Comment: You don't actually have to look inside the .dsc, the Sources file contains the hash for .tar.gz as well.

Comment: Also, you don't have to download the files yourself, they should be already cached locally in Apt's state directory (Dir::State option in apt_preferences)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see that warning is because the source packages are signed by the developer's own key, while the binary packages you get from the repo are signed by the repo signing key. Since `ubuntu-keyring` only gives the keyring of the final repo (`debian-keyring` actually also provides the public keys of all of its maintainers), `apt` can't find the key and considers the package unauthenticated.

Therefore, the solution here is to import the key from a keyserver. You can also look up the source package on Launchpad (`pam` is [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam)), click on the email address of the person who made the last change for a package, and check the key fingerprint from there.

In this case, the last person to change the package was Stéphane Graber, and it just so happens that his key is in `debian-keyring` (specifically, in `/usr/share/keyrings/debian-maintainers.gpg`). You can install the `debian-keyring` package, export his key from that keyring, and import that key into your own keyring so that `apt` can verify that it is properly signed.

Comment: `debian-keyring` is already installed, but the key appears to not be there: `$ gpg --export 64792D67 --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-maintainers.gpg` `gpg: WARNING: nothing exported`

Comment: Strange. I did a `grep` and couldn't find his name, but I remember seeing his key there. I'm going to look into this.