# Why did Ubuntu source repository key signature fail with security warning?

Tags: apt, gnupg, source-code, official-repositories

Downloading Ubuntu source code gave a security warning:

```
# apt-get source gedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
NOTICE: 'gedit' packaging is maintained in the 'Bzr' version control system at:
https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/gedit/ubuntu
Please use:
bzr branch https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/gedit/ubuntu
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Need to get 3,116 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main gedit 3.10.4-0ubuntu10 (dsc) [2,650 B]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main gedit 3.10.4-0ubuntu10 (tar) [3,086 kB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main gedit 3.10.4-0ubuntu10 (diff) [26.7 kB]
Fetched 3,116 kB in 5s (611 kB/s)
gpgv: Signature made Sat 04 Apr 2015 22:31:17 BST using RSA key ID 778FA6F5
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu10.dsc
```

It downloaded the code anyway. But why did it's key fail? And does the warning mean the downloaded files can't be trusted?

Answer (score 1):

According to [What's the official method for checking integrity of a source package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509487/whats-the-official-method-for-checking-integrity-of-a-source-package) and [How to get apt-get source verification working?](https://superuser.com/questions/626810/how-to-get-apt-get-source-verification-working) you can try these:

1. `sudo apt-get install debian-keyring`
2. `gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 9F1B8B32`

Comment: That's an answer to a different question, but helpful all the same, thank you.