# What does this command mean: 'grep main/source/Sources.gz Release'? Where is the file main/source/Sources.gz?

Tags: apt, software-sources

I'm trying to check the integrity of a source package following this tutorial (https://askubuntu.com/a/509816/978081), however, I don't understand step 4 onward as already described in the title.

4. Compare hashes obtained from sha256sum Sources.gz and grep main/source/Sources.gz Release

Can you help me?

Comment: where is this file reside: main/source/Sources.gz?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you misunderstands the grep command

```
grep main/source/Sources.gz Release
```

The command looks for a text-string "main/source/Sources.gz" in a file called "Release" in current directory.

Comment: Soren A is right, but if you did want to `locate Sources.gz` that should work, `man locate` gives you the manual for slocate/mlocate or whatever app provides your `locate` command. `sudo updatedb` updates locate's database.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much :D

Comment: @Soren A: Could you explain steps 5 & 6 for me? Where is the .dsc file?

Comment: @logbasex basically run the commands mentioned and compare the output. If you want to know what the different commands (sha256sum, zcat, cat, sed) are doing you can look them up with `man command` (like `man zcat`) or google them.