# How to find GnuPG keys for apt-get source?

Tags: apt, gnupg

Why trying to download the `dbus` package using: `$ apt-get source dbus`,I get the following warning:

```
gpgv: Signature made Wed 17 Sep 2014 11:10:07 PM CST using RSA key ID A744BE93
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./dbus_1.6.18-0ubuntu4.2.dsc
```

How can I find the RSA key with id: `A744BE93`?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/56841/gpg-cant-check-signature

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in your keyring using this command

```
sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A744BE93
```

Once added, retry `apt-get source dbus`.