# "fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo' " upon running repo init <...>

Tags: 16.04, apt, repository, git, gnupg

I've been running into this issue every time I run a `repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/le/le/manifest.git -b [branch] -m [manifest]`  command.

```
  >> 
  >> repo 1.12.16
  stderr:
  >> gpg: Signature made Thu 01 May 2014 01:34:18 PM PDT using RSA key ID 692B382C
  >> gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
  >> error: could not verify the tag 'v1.12.16'
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

Then I installed the `repo` package via `sudo apt-get install repo` which seems to install the repo in `/usr/bin` dir so upon running `$/usr/bin/repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/le/le/manifest.git -b [branch] -m [manifest]` , I now see:

```
repo: error: "git" failed with exit status 1
  stderr:
  >> gpg: Signature made Thu 22 June 2012 01:14:15 PM PDT using RSA key ID 692B382C
  >> gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
  >> error: could not verify the tag 'v1.12.16'
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

I [tried this](https://askubuntu.com/a/198420/1152323) approach to no avail.

Comment: Since 16.04 is EOL in April of this year you may want to upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04 and then try again.

Comment: i don't think it's specific to 16.04. Other repo commands have worked before